What commands to include in shell_escape_commands to enable inkscape for pdflatex?
I use the svg package to generate an image (pdf file) with inkscape.
How should I set "shell_escape_commands" in texmf.cnf to make this work?
When I set "shell_escape = t" in texmf.cnf, it works.
But with
shell_escape = p
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
mv,\
rm,\
uname,\
mkdir,\
inkscape,\

it fails.
Any ideas?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

the tex log file lists every command attempted, but note that if shell redirect commands such as >  or separators such as ; or some other features are used then it is not possible to allow the use of the command without using --shell-escape  for security reasons.
running a trivial example with --shell-escape
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{example.svg}

\end{document}

the log shows entries such as
runsystem(uname -s > "aa983.w18")...executed.

runsystem(rm -- "aa983.w18")...executed.

runsystem(inkscape "example.svg" -D --export-latex --export-filename="example_svg-tex.pdf")...executed.

runsystem(inkscape "example.svg" -D --export-latex \relax --without-gui --export-pdf="example_svg-tex.pdf")...executed.

I think to get this to run in restricted shell mode you would need to modify the package to adjust the calls.  As well as avoiding > I don't think you would want to add rm to the restricted shell list.
